# How do I rewrite Objective C options bitmasks to to Ruby for RubyMotion?

Tags: objective-c, rubymotion

How do I rewrite:

```
NSUInteger options = kCFCalendarUnitYear | kCFCalendarUnitMonth | kCFCalendarUnitDay;
```

To Ruby for Rubymotion?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost the exact same way. The only difference really is that since Ruby requires constants to start with a capital letter, you must use a capital `K` instead:

```
options = KCFCalendarUnitYear | KCFCalendarUnitMonth | KCFCalendarUnitDay
# returns 28, same as in Objective-C.
```

Answer (score 2):

Dylan Markow's answer is correct. Sometimes you might also want to create a bitmask from an array of values programmatically and you don't have the luxury of using the bitwise or operator directly.

For instance:

```
options = []
options << KCFCalendarUnitYear
options << KCFCalendarUnitMonth
options << KCFCalendarUnitDay
```

A nice little trick here is to use inject like so:

```
options.inject(:|)
```

It has the added advantage of looking like the face of a monkey.